# Remote Desktop XRDP install

Tags: lubuntu, remote, xrdp

I followed the directions for installing a remote desktop server XRDP on my Lubuntu virtual machine. On the third step I am supposed to update the file

```
sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

for that update do I just go to the bottom of the file and add `startxfce4`?

I did that and it still does not work

Please advise, thank you

I followed these steps :

1. Step 1 – Install xRDP

   Open Terminal (Crtl+Alt+T) and execute the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install xrdp
   ```
2. Step 2 – Install XFCE4 ( Unity doesn't seem to support xRDP in Ubuntu 14.04; although, in Ubuntu 12.04 it was supported ). That's why we install Xfce4.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xfce4
   ```
3. Step 3 – Configure xRDP

   In this step, we modify two files to make sure xRDP uses Xfce4. First we need to create, or edit, our `.xsession` file in our home directory. We can either use nano or simply redirect an echo statement (easier):

   ```
   echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
   ```

   The second file we need to edit is the startup file for xRDP, so it will start Xfce4.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
   ```

   The content should look like this (pay attention to the last line and ignore `. /etc/X11/Xsession`):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
     . /etc/default/locale
   export LANG LANGUAGE
   fi
   startxfce4
   ```
4. Step 4 – Restart xRDP

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but doesn't it need to read `start xfce4`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1012146/edit) your question and provide the link to the original web page where you got the four steps from. What does "it still does not work" mean? Please copy and paste all error and output messages you see into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit only one file to have xfce desktop environment started

if you are the only user needing remote access, you can simply edit (or create) the `~/.xsession` file and issue the following following command

- either

  ```
  echo xfce4-session >> ~/.xsession
  ```
- or if multiple users are using the system, you can edit the `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` and add the following line at the end

  ```
  echo xfce4-session >> ~/.xsession
  ```

This command will automatically populate the `.xsession` file of all the users

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 (as mentioned in your question somewhere), you can try to get more information in the step by step guide provided [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305)