# Native RDP on Ubuntu only works if I login from Hyper-V console first

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop

I just installed `22.04.01` as Hyper-V VM on Windows 11.

And I want to use the "native" RDP that it provides. After some hiccup ([Native RDP on Ubuntu 22.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426376/native-rdp-on-ubuntu-22-04-not-working)) I managed to connect to it from Windows 11.

However there is new problem - if I reboot Ubuntu the Windows RDP client does not connect as if Ubuntu does not listen to the RDP port:

[image]

But once I connect to the VM using Hyper-V console and login, the RDP client starts to work. I can even close Hyper-V console and I still able to RDP. Once the VM rebooted the issue appears again.

I suspect Ubuntu service `gnome-remote-desktop` setup that it only starts for user and not for OS (I dont know much about Ubuntu - how to check that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect Ubuntu service gnome-remote-desktop setup that it only starts for user and not for OS

That's true. gnome-remote-desktop starts only as a user service, when it is enabled.
Currently, gnome-remote-desktop only implements remote-assistance sessions.

Headless sessions (which include remote login) is not implemented yet.
However, there is work upstream ongoing in implementing that: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop/-/merge_requests/139

Comment: Question to Pascal Nowack: do you have a guestimate as to when that functionality will become available to users? My headless server is eagerly awaiting it.